# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq

i am trying to access MQ queues using JMS. i am getting the below

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no mqjbnd05 in java.library.path
```

i am passing

```
-Djava.library.path="C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere MQ\java\lib"
```

as the VM argument while running the program in eclipse. This issue is discussed quite a lot on the net but with out any conclusion. Has anyone resolved this? TIA.

Comment: Did you check if the directory `C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere MQ\java\lib` actually contains the native library `mqjbnd05.dll`?

Comment: the thing is i dont find this mqjbn05.dll, all i have is mqjbnd.dll the path for which i have specified at the VM arg section

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably have some older MQ jar files either in your CLASSPATH, in the lib or in the EAR.
Remove them and you should be fine.
You should not put MQ files in your EAR or in the WEB-INF/lib folders. They should be in the classpath of your appserver.

Comment: @hakish - Actually they are, you can access MQ7 with MQ6 and vice-versa, you just cannot use version 7 .dll files with v6 jars.

Answer (score 27):

As I had to deal with this error myself; and it took me a lot of time to find the right answer, I'd like to share it with the next one, who comes along this thread...

Actually the solution to the problem was very simple (at least in my case). It was not related to any `CLASSPATH`, `java.library.path` or installation issues.

I simply forgot to switch the `MQConnectionFactory` into the Client mode.

This has to be done, by simply calling

```
cf.setTransportType(WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
```

or

```
cf.setTransportType(WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_BINDINGS_THEN_CLIENT);
```

or any other connection type, that fits your needs.
By default, the ConnectionFactory is in "Binding" mode (`WMQ_CM_BINDINGS`), which is intended for local server installations, as it is is stated in the IBM Documentation:

> To connect to a queue manager in **bindings mode**, a WebSphere MQ classes for JMS application **must run on the same system** on which the queue manager is running.

This transport type is the same as the `XMSC_WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE` (`WMQConstants.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE`) property, when using JNDI or the `JmsFactoryFactory`.

The same should apply to the other ConnectionFactory types: `MQQueueConnectionFactory`, `MQTopicConnectionFactory`, `MQXAConnectionFactory`, `MQXAQueueConnectionFactory` and `MQXATopicConnectionFactory`

Check the IMB Knowledge Center for more information about the different connection/binding options:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q031720_.htm
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q030560_.htm

Comment: The error is misleading. This is answer gives a hint of what should happen. You should go to the MQ Explorer and change the transport type to "Client" instead of "Binding".

Comment: Your solution is not actually a solution. You are just working with the CLIENT mode and not BINIDING mode, so by changing the mode your program ran. However, if you still need to use BINDING mode then what you will do ?

Comment: @Som Well as I wrote in my answer Binding Mode is intended for connections to a local server (on the same machine). So if you actually want to bind to a local MQ Server instance and you are still getting this issue, then you should probably just do what the error message suggests (adding the directory where your `mqjbnd05` is located to your `java.library.path`). If you don't have the dll, than there might be a version conflict. But I have never used Binding Mode myself; so I can't help much with this.

Comment: What a ridiculous default. Thanks IBM :-(

Answer (score 3):

I came across this while connecting using IBM MQ api.
I didn't find this issue to be related to classpath either.

This happened to me when I instantiated `MQQueueManager` before setting `MQEnvironment`'s `hostname` and `channel`.
Just ensure that your code does not do that and that it instantiates the manager after the environment is set. Something like..

```
MQEnvironment.hostname = "mq hostname";
MQEnvironment.channel = "mq channel";
..more code..
this._queueManager = new MQQueueManager(qManager);
```

(Observed that it's OK to set `MQEnvironment.port` after `MQQueueManager` is initialized, but one would probably initialize everything related to `MQEnvironment` together)

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if you *actually* installed MQ **Client** instead of MQ **Server**.

IBM has even written a [whole help page](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21158430) about it:

> ### [WebSphere MQ Client installation missing mqjb*.dll files](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21158430)
>
> #### Problem(Abstract)
>
> You install the WebSphere MQ Client and notice three dll's are missing from the `\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere MQ\Java\lib\` directory.
>
> #### Symptom
>
> The following dlls appear in the directory on a server install, but are not part of the Java™ client:
>
> - 03/17/2003 10:59a 19,456 mqjbdf02.dll
> - 03/17/2003 10:59a 57,856 mqjbnd05.dll
> - 03/17/2003 10:59a 36,864 MQXAi02.dll
>
> The subdirectory \jdbc\ appears on the server, but not on the client machine.
>
> - 03/17/2003 10:59a 61,440 jdbcdb2.dll
> - 03/17/2003 10:59a 61,440 jdbcora.dll
>
> #### Cause
>
> The files are missing because they are not provided nor needed in a client install.
>
> #### Resolving the problem
>
> The files are only included in the WebSphere MQ Server product.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy recipe: [Tell the Java VM to Load the DLL](http://www.inonit.com/cygwin/jni/helloWorld/load.html). Is your code similiar, e.g. do you use `System.loadLibrary` to load `mqjbnd05.dll`?

If yes - does it work outside eclipse, like starting the application from the command line? If this is the case, you could try starting the whole eclipse IDE with that library path.

And sometimes we have trouble with pathnames that contain spaces. Copy the dll to `C:\`, put that on the lib path and try again.

---

Ah, that's the problem, the specified dll is missing. [This blog has a solution](http://krishtechtalk.blogspot.com/2008/05/problem-connecting-to-websphere-mq-in.html). Good luck!

Comment: the thing is i dont find this mqjbn05.dll, all i have is mqjbnd.dll the path for which i have specified at the VM arg section

Answer (score 0):

In my case when I set the transport type , the error goes away. I was using MQConnectionFactory

```
mQQueueConnectionFactory.setTransportType( JMSC.MQJMS_TP_CLIENT_MQ_TCPIP);
```